# Hibernate filter with this

Tags: hibernate

I want to filter data form collection so that only the newest element is chosen. I have creation_date variable that tells me when an element was created. 
In order to get the newest one I want write sth like that:
condition = "creation_date >= (select max(creation_date) from this) - where this should be - referance to ... this - elements associated with the parent (mapped) object. But hibernate doesnt figure out that it should replace this with some clever name used by him to access table from db.
Here is my code:

```
    <set name="elements" table="elements">
        <key column="ID_ELEMENT" />
        ...

        <filter name="limitToLatestVersions"
            condition="creation_date >= (select max(creation_date) from ?my_problem )"/>

    </set>
```